# Qt (qml): Access Bundle file in Qt for Webview Url in ios?

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml, qwebview

As i am new in ios development for Qt, i don't have idea to call bundle data file as url for [Webview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtwebview-webview.html).

**Note ::** Webview doesn't support resource system for url.

Took [qt minibrwoser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html) example for implementation.

```
    Update in .pro file, Added html_file folder as Bundle data:

    ios {
    deployment.files = $${PWD}\\html
    deployment.path =
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += deployment
    }

Update in main.qml file
 WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "file:assets-library:/assest/html/view.html" 

//url didn't load on runtime (not sure how to access bundle data html file at runtime)

        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                console.error(loadRequest.errorString);
        }
    }
```

[image]

I am able to access same page in android with following code update:

```
  WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "file:///android_asset/html/view.html"
        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                console.error(loadRequest.errorString);
        }
    }
```

**Question:: How to call bundle_data file as url in ios?**

If anyone come across similar problem and know a solution. Please guide me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Using QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() can be access path of executable file and content items of executable(.app) file.

Add following in main.qml

```
#include<QCoreApplication>


initialUrl="file:/" + QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/html/view.html"

 context->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("initialUrl"),
                                Utils::fromUserInput(initialUrl));
```

Reference:: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath

```
WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: initialUrl

//url didn't load on runtime (not sure how to access bundle data html file at runtime)

        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                console.error(loadRequest.errorString);
        }
    }
```

Reference :: https://forum.qt.io/topic/67214/path-to-image-in-xcassets-folder-ios/2